# Como hacer un Pivot dinámico con fechas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server,

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = GETDATE(); 

SELECT 'Total' AS Concept, 
  [10/1/2022], [11/1/2022], [12/1/2022], [13/1/2022], [14/1/2022]
FROM  
(
  SELECT debt, expiration
  FROM debtors
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  SUM(debt)
  FOR expiration IN ([10/1/2022], [11/1/2022], [12/1/2022], [13/1/2022], [14/1/2022])
) AS PivotTable;
```

y quiero que las fechas del vencimiento (expiration) sean dinámicas a la variable @today, intente ponerle entre los corchetes pero no es una sintaxis correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Crear un pivot dinámico es más complejo que uno estático y requiere de tener claro el resultado que uno espera.

Con el escenario que ofreces:

```
Create table debtors (id int identity(1,1),expiration date, debt int)
go
insert into debtors(expiration, debt)
values
('20220101',10),
('20220102',11),
('20220103',12),
('20220104',13),
('20220105',14),
('20220106',15),
('20220107',16),
('20220108',17),
('20220109',18),
('20220110',19),
('20220111',20),
('20220112',21),
('20220113',22),
('20220113',22),
('20220113',22),
('20220114',23),
('20220114',23),
('20220114',23),
('20220115',24);
go
```

Una tabla con varias columnas y varias filas, por fechas diferentes.

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = '20220115'; 
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
 
 SELECT @columns = STUFF(
 (
SELECT top(5)
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(expiration))
 FROM
   (SELECT  DISTINCT expiration
    FROM debtors
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 expiration desc
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, ''); 

Set @sql = N'
SELECT *  
  
FROM  
(
  SELECT debt, expiration
  FROM debtors
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  SUM(debt)
  FOR expiration IN ('+@columns+N')
) AS PivotTable;'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

En vez de utilizar getdate para la variable, yo he usado una fecha prefijada, porque mis datos solo tienen valores en ese rango, y además para no tener demasiadas columnas y ver que funciona igualmente, he limitado a 5 columnas la salida.

[image: Resultado]

El pivot dinamíco se establece, seleccionando en una variable el nombre de las columnas que va a utilizar: (Aquí es donde he puesto el top 5, para limitar la salida)

```
SELECT STUFF(
 (
SELECT top(5)
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(expiration))
 FROM
   (SELECT  DISTINCT expiration
    FROM debtors
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 expiration desc
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '');
```

[image: res2]

Cuando ya tiene asignado los nombres a la variable, se construye igual que uno estático pero se le asignan esas columnas almacenadas en la variable.

[Pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)